# java.lang.ClassFormatError after minor code change

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I restrated my program and it just blew up. All I changed in it were some String.format() returns and reverting those changes did not make this error go away. When I research the error it appears to be related to Maven? But im using ANT to build the project.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file InHouseLeague/Workers/BotListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.schwering.irc.moep.MoepIRC.run(MoepIRC.java:831)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The code its referenceing (I havent touched in weeks)

```
public void run() {
    updateTab(Util.CONSOLEWINDOWINDEX, "# Trying to connect to "+ host, 
        serverColor);
    enableConnectMenuItem(false);
    username = username.toLowerCase();
    if (!useSSL) {
    conn = new BotConnection(host, portMin, portMax, password, nickname, 
        username, realname);
    } else {
    BotSSLConnection sslconn = new BotSSLConnection(host, portMin, portMax, 
        password, nickname, username, realname);
    if (!autoAcceptSSLCerts)
        sslconn.addTrustManager(new AskTrustManager());
    conn = sslconn;
    }
    conn.addIRCEventListener(new BotListener(this)); //ERROR POINTS TO HERE
    conn.setColors(true); 
    conn.setPong(false); 
    conn.setDaemon(true);
    try {
    conn.connect();
    this.isConnected = conn.isConnected();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
    String reason = "";
    if (exc.getMessage() != null) {
        reason = ": "+ exc.getMessage();
    }
    updateTab(Util.CONSOLEWINDOWINDEX, "# Couldn't connect"+ reason, 
        serverColor);
    enableConnectMenuItem(true);
    exc.printStackTrace();
    this.isConnected = false;
    }
}
```

The changes I made before this happened:

From:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String returnStr = String.format("%s(ELO: %d):", getTeamName(), teamELO);
        for (IPlayer player : roster) {
            returnStr = String.format("%s %s", returnStr, player.getUserName());
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
```

To

```
    public String toString() {
        String returnStr = String.format("%s[%d]:", getTeamName(), teamELO);
        for (IPlayer player : roster) {
            returnStr = String.format("%s %s;", returnStr, player.getUserName());
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
```

Comment: I dont even know where to begin with showing the code. As I mentioned the change was so minor. It was literally reformatting a string.

Comment: What kind of app is this? Is in a web app hosted in some kind of container? A lot of the google results say that it's some weird dependency issue. What's your class path look like? What's the ant target look like?

Comment: If you revert the changes back, whether the error is coming?

Comment: I grabbed a new .jar of the library its using and it appears to have fixed it. I have no idea what would have broken it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagnostic is:

Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file InHouseLeague/Workers/BotListener

You did not say if code changes was in the class InHouseLeague.Workers.BotListener, or is it a library class. Anyway, normally any code changes cannot make a compiler to produce a method without code attrubute. The class file was spoiled in another way, for example, it was a hardware device error.